# Bootstrap grid row offset when changing font-size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to make site navigation through Bootstrap Grid system.
I want to make 3 columns with two rows with this layout:

```
|Title   |            |Login|
|Subtitle|Menu buttons|     |
```

Code works correctly, until i set `font-size` for title and subtitle. Can anybody help me? Snippet: http://www.bootply.com/GLEf6MfmxE

**HTML:**

```
  <header> 
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-4" id="title">Foo title</div>
       <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
       <div class="col-xs-2">Login</div>
       <div class="col-xs-2" id="subtitle">Bar subtitle</div>
       <div class="col-xs-1">Menu 1</div>
       <div class="col-xs-1">Menu 2</div>
     </div> 
   </div>
 </header>
```

**Custom CSS:**

```
#title{
    font-size: 2em;
}

#subtitle {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to learn that, for the different row, you have to use another row class as you are working on two row so each column must be on their own row class like this check the following code. i am sure this code will help you to understand.

```
  <header> 
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4" id="title">Foo title</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">Login</div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-2" id="subtitle">Bar subtitle</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">Menu 1</div>
          <div class="col-xs-1">Menu 2</div>
      </div> 
   </div>
  </header>
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's grid system allows up to 12 columns across the page, so you have to fill 12 columns for row.

Look at this: http://www.bootply.com/SRezJSXWsE

ps: As you can see I update the css too, in order to align your Login to the right.